# Wildfly suddenly return 404 for deployed EAR

Tags: jms, wildfly-10, activemq-artemis

After successful deploying EAR on Wildfly 10 and working fine after some days it returns 404 for the URL of deployed EAR (Server not shutdown), Only I had this WARN in server.log file

```
WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (Thread-25 (ActiveMQ-server-
org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$2@43653a52-
915383569)) AMQ222010: Critical IO Error, shutting down the server. 
file=NIOSequentialFile
/home/wildfly/wildfly/standalone/data/activemq/largemessages/2317811.msg, 
message=/home/wildfly/wildfly/standalone/data/activemq/largemessages 
/2317811.msg (Too many open files): 
ActiveMQIOErrorException[errorType=IO_ERROR
```

I use JMS for application auditing

Answer (score 0):

When ActiveMQ Artemis encounters a critical IO error it shuts itself down in order to prevent compromising data integrity.  In your case it looks like the broker has exceeded the limit of open files enforced by the operating system.

Comment: but why this happen and how I can prevent it? ( We increase the limit of opened files before)

Comment: It looks like you're sending what the broker interprets as "large" messages which are stored as individual files on disk.  In other words, 1 message results in 1 file.  Therefore, you can either send smaller messages so they aren't treated as "large", or you can increase the minLargeMessageSize on the client, or you can increase the file limit on the operating system.

Comment: First Thanks a lot Justin but I want to know also why the opened file for the message not closed after message had been consumed? Is there any problem in sender/consumer classes or in configurations?

Comment: Is there direct evidence that the file is not closed after the message is consumed?

Comment: I added log after consumer handler end  also I had pool of consumers so I think that Wildfly/ActiveMQ will close the file when the consumer return back to the pool to serve other messages also I close sender connection at the end of sending.

Comment: If you believe this is a bug in ActiveMQ Artemis then you should either follow-up on the ActiveMQ User mailing list or open a JIRA at https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/ARTEMIS.  In either case you should fully explain your use-case and include a reproducible test-case.  It would probably also be a good idea to reproduce the issue on the latest release of Artemis (2.4 at this point) without Wildfly in the mix.